# How to allow CRUD operations in a DataGridView in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, datagridview, crud

I've been having a lot of trouble to bind a database (I'm using Northwind) to a DataGridView.
I've tried various approaches, but none worked for all operations, only some.
I've also asked on other sites, but so far I haven't gotten any helpful advice.

Is there a tutorial that covers really all CRUD operations (or a combination of several tutorials that together cover all)?

Especially the delete operation is causing me headaches as the only tip I've gotten is to put my delete code into some DataGridView event, yet the problem is that I cannot find a way to determine what exactly the user wants to delete and the KeyDown event won't fire for the delete key.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thank you very much. That document is very helpful.
I have another question though, I have a DataTable as DataSource for the DataGridView.
To update it for execution of user input CRUD operations, do I need to manually insert data into the DataTable or is it enough to just built a regular SQL command with the adapter's DeleteCommand/InsertCommand/etc properties and then just pass the yet unmodified DataTable as argument in the Update method?

I.e. would this get me the desired result of insert a new row into the db table with the values the user has just input into the DataGridView?

```
private void DGV_Nwind_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO [" + table.TableName + "] VALUES ("; //sql command base

        //add values to command
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            sql += "'" + e.Row.Cells[i].ToString() + "'"; 

            if (i < (e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)) 
            {
                sql += ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                sql += ")";
            }
        }

        //update table
        con.OleAdapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql);
        con.OleAdapter.Update(table);
    }
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, Web application? What programming language?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a C# Lib & App, that let's you create your object, CRUD operations (using BLL & DAL) and Web UI to perform that CRUD operations.

http://manacodegenerator.codeplex.com

It's lightweight and pretty straightforward to use, it helped me get rid of those boring hours of repetitive code creation.

I'm constantly evolving it since it's a tool that I use on a daily basis.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WPF application, here is a tutorial for how to do CRUD operations:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx#updates

Basically, you would tie into the row deleted event and in your method you would process the deleted row.

Here is a doc on using the DataGridView.  In it is information on tying into the Delete event and other CRUD operations:

http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Projecttest
{
    class Program
    {
        struct student
        {
            public string stid;
            public string stname;
            public string stage;

        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] st = new student[4];
            int choice;
            string confirm;

            int count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Select operation to Perform");
            Console.WriteLine("1. ADD");
            Console.WriteLine("2. UPDATE");
            Console.WriteLine("3. DELETE");
            Console.WriteLine("4. SHOW");
            do
            {
                Console.Write("enter your choice(1-4):");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Add(st, count);
                        count++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Update(st);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Delete(st);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Show(st);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Selection\n");
                        break;
                }

                Console.Write("Press Y or y to continue:");

                confirm = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            } while (confirm == "Y" || confirm == "y");
        }

        static void Add(student[] st, int count)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            st[count].stid = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
            st[count].stname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter student age: ");
            st[count].stage = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Show(student[] st)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (st[count].stid != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nStudent ID : " + st[count].stid);
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Name : " + st[count].stname);
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Age : " + st[count].stage);
                }
            }
        }
        static void Delete(student[] st)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            string studid = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (studid == st[count].stid)
                {
                    st[count].stid = null;
                    st[count].stname = null;
                    st[count].stage = null;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Update(student[] st)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter student ID: ");
            string studid = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int count = 0; count < st.Length; count++)
            {
                if (studid == st[count].stid)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
                    st[count].stname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter student age: ");
                    st[count].stage = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```